# What steps can I take to get an ipa file generated by xcode onto a test ios device?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want GUARANTEED steps to get this to work.
I've pulled my hair out on this task many times since I started doing this work 6 months ago, and the feedback from itunes and the organizer is non-existent.

I have full access, I can go into the apple dev centre and do whatever is necessary and I know my way around xcode now.
Currently, when I connect my iPhone and click applications under the iphone [on the left in the organizer] the add and remove buttons are disabled and I can't click and drag ipa files into it.

If I open itunes and click and drag my app into the applications area for my macbook, it works and overwrites the current app, but when I try to click update, then sync, it successfully syncs, but still has the button saying "update" instead of "install", and when I view the phone it says " failed to install" or some other ridiculously generic message.

I've also tried to create a new profile, but when i use the add button in the organizer to attempt to add it to my iPhone it accept the file, but doesn't shot i on the list. I click and drag and it's the same thing, no error and it looks like it'll accept it, but it doesn't show up on the list. So I can't seem to attempt to add a new profile.

BTW, The device is in the devices list and has a valid profile [and the profile has the device in the list of devices (and the UDIDs match)].

I'm looking for some solid steps to guarantee the app will be installed on the phone without these headaches.

Xcode: 4.5.1
iphone: 6.1.3

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated. Honestly, I'm ready to quit my job because the stress this software is causing me, this is ridiculous.

(my frustration: I've had compilation errors that are resolved by restarting xcode, I've had to restart my computer to resolve profile issues, and far too many times I've had to flush everything just to deploy to the app store... I've never dealt with such a terrible awful piece of software and toolchain in my entire life [and I've used Windows and VS!])

Answer (score 1):

Check out TestFlight - http://testflightapp.com

They give step by step instructions on how to distribute ad-hoc versions.  Its very easy to set up.

Set up your provisioning profiles, build/archive your app, then distribute it via TestFlight.

See http://help.testflightapp.com/ for help.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Steps:

1 - Create a provision profile Distribution for your app ( don't forget to add the devices, witch will test this. Its very important because case you dont add then, they will not have permition to install the app.). After create download and double click it. Don't delete yet, you will need it to upload after.

2 - Go to your project, Build / Targets / Build Settings / Code Signing and set the provision profile you create.

3 - Build the project. If its ok, click in product, archive

4 - Click in Distribute, Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment. Save your .ipa

5 - Go to [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) Create the app and upload the build.

6 - Go to Apps Builds and click in your app.

7 - Go to Permitions and Upload the Provision Profile!! Now you can choose in this list who you want to notify about the app to download!

8 -  (Optional) Go to People and create/manage your team giving the right priorities.

You should implement the SDK case you want to manage the Sessions. Its Very simple, just follow the tutorial [Documentation](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc/1.2.4/) and the sdk [iOS SDK Download](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/download/)

Comment: Is it simply defacto that everyone uses test flight? Is there step-by-step without using test flight?

Comment: People use TestFlight because it works well.  It will do what you're asking.  Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to install .ipa file without using testflight

1. Extract the folder which contains files .ipa and .mobileprovision .
2. Open iTunes and connect your device.
3. Drag and drop .mobileprovision on Library->Apps group section of
   iTunes.
4. Repeat above step with .ipa .

   Sync your device and it's done.